# Using multiple front end frameworks simultaneously

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, frontend, web-frameworks, html5boilerplate

[This article](http://haeckdesign.com/blog/design/standards/responsive-frameworks) seems to suggest it's common for people to use multiple front end frameworks when a developing a site. Is this actually done?

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere where it suggests that, which is good, because it would be a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion: this is not something that people do.